# Handling the navigation bar (or styling the string?)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation, navigationbar

I am currently writing an app that includes a **BottomNavigationBar (android studio)**

but I got a problem:
**I want the layouts to switch (or at least the TextViews inside each)**,

currently **the navigation is not doing more than switching between single strings.** so how can I make it work? please give me a step-by-step guide because I am fairly new to this whole stuff.

here's some code:

```
package com.john.doe.mycvasapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Personal extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mTextMessage;

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.personal:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.personal1);
                return true;
            case R.id.school:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.school1);
                return true;
            case R.id.work:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.work1);
                return true;
            case R.id.skills:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.skills1);
                return true;
            case R.id.lastly:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.lastly1);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_persoenliche_daten);

    mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}

}
```

*thanks for all the incoming help,
regards, guy from internet*

Comment: can you answer?